# Google Map : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am getting this error while adding a map to my application and I don't understand why am I getting this error. I am trying to solve it for 2 days now but couldn't solve it. I am so much frustrated because of this. Please help me with this. I'll really appreciate any help. I followed steps from Google's official website. Here is what I did : 
I created a new Google Map Activity, so, most of the code was automatically included. After that, I downloaded the key from console.developers.google.com.

MapsActivity.java :

```
package com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

activity_maps.xml :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo.MapsActivity" />
```

build.gradle (Module : app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

This is the error :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
```

Comment: What is even more disappointing is that instead of answering the question, people are making it unclear or not useful.

Comment: Add these lines in your AndroidManifest.xml-  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this.

Comment: Have you tried inserting an SD card on your device? Please refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488967/binary-xml-file-line-error-inflating-class-fragment-only-on-android-6-0-m).

Answer (score 1):

Just **replace** this .

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:name="com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo.MapsActivity"
 />
```

And Add both

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Edit**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Update your manifest

```
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: @SybilNaushad check my edited answer .Hope it will works

Comment: did you add `<uses-permission android:name="com.example.sybilnaushad.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />`

Comment: I did. But it still gives me the same error. Sometimes it also says in the logcat "Too much output to process"

Comment: Can the key be the problem? As far as I know, I have created the key properly and I have also enabled the Android Maps API in the developers console website.

Comment: read this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: It was some issue with my phone's GPS. It worked on other phones.

Comment: @SybilNaushad Ohh . You can check GPS & NETWORK Both